# Does the colon character fit with JSON?

Tags: java, json

I try design a simple all purpose Data Structure that must be convertable to JSON and back. Since I have names and types I need to find an expression for that.

So I look for something like `name+type` or `name<type>` or `name:type` (which i like) or `name|type` or `type[name]`.

Are there any problems with that? I mean the `:` is already taken so I need to enclose the name and type (which is always a good idea).

Anything I need to know?

Comment: Something like that: `"name": { "type": "someType", "value": "someValue" }`?

Comment: Your design seems to have 2 conflicting terms: `simple` and `all purpose`

Comment: @Ceiling There is a saying "The truth is always simple and seldom complex" - So simple just regards to least complex (or near to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon `:` is part of the JSON syntax so you must enclose a name that contains a colon (as any name) in double quotes `"`. This

```
{
    "foo:bar": "BAR",
    "foo:baz": "BAZ"
}
```

is valid JSON. Check it at http://jsonlint.com/

The very simple JSON syntax can be read on the [JSON.org site](http://json.org/).

Comment: Is there any standard using this notation?